# is it possible to move the UIScrollView indicator from the right side to the left?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I realize I can rotate the cells and move the indicator by displaying the scroll view "upside down" but that requires a lot of other rotations, and manipulating of information to make the Table scroll properly.

Thanks for the time

Comment: This should be a system-wide setting so that left-handed users have scrollbars on the right, and right-handed users have scrollbars on the left. I've been telling this since years.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Actually, it is possible by changing the `scrollIndicatorInsets` property to restrict the indicator to a small area on the left side:

```
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,tableView.bounds.size.width-10);
```

Comment: Good, though it depends on your constant `10` matching the width of the scroll view... technically that's an unsafe assumption, but practically it's feasible.

Comment: Just to clarify further, 10 should be the width of the indicator itself, not the scroll view. I think this is what @rickster meant to say.

Comment: actually, 7 is the width of the indicator.

Comment: Anything you can do with scrollIndicatorInsets tends to depend on the size of the scroll bar indicator, so it's probably as safe as anything.

Comment: After some measuring, it looks like `width - 8.5` is the appropriate amount. In my case, I transformed the scroll view so the top is at the bottom. Doing this puts the scroll bars on the right just like normal.

Answer (score 7):

I like Jeremy Jay's solution (though I haven't tested it), but just to thoroughly explore the idea... here's another that might be worth trying (though it's also untested):

Use two scroll views.

One scroll view (we'll call this the "real" one) contains your content but has its indicators hidden. Another scroll view contains no content but has its `contentSize` set to match that of the "real" scroll view's. When the "real" scroll view's `contentOffset` changes (as observed via delegate messages), change the "fake" scroll view's offset to match. (Check out the scroll views session from WWDC 2012 for more on the idea of using a scroll view without a content view.)

In theory (again, I haven't tested this), you now have a scroll indicator view that's separate from your original scroll view, and you can place it wherever you like in relation to the original. Layer it on top of the original and move/size it so it occupies a narrow sliver on the left, and you have a left-side scroll indicator. (Alternately, layer it atop the original and flip it horizontally with an affine transform.) Put it somewhere else entirely to take your UI on a trip to crazy town. (Or don't.) Make sure you make it ignore touches if it's layered on top, though.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to achieve this (if you're not using row actions) without having to calculate insets or messing with additional table views, would be to transform the table view across the Y-axis (flip) and then transform the cells back when you get them.

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
```

and then

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
```